# Cant Upload Photos Using Php

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a photo to mysql database using php, however I'm getting the following error:

```
 failed to open stream: Permission denied in '/The location of my php file' on line 40.

 move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpgZi5gV to 'The location where the image will be stored'
```

Here is my code:

```
$dir = $path;
$default = "default.png";

// get Filename
$filename = basename($filen['name']);
$targetFilePath = $dir.$filename;
$filetype = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!empty($filename)) {
    //allowed file formats

    $allowedFormats = array("jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif", "pdf");

    if(in_array($filetype, $allowedFormats)) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($filen['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath)) {
            return $targetFilePath;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're dealing with some permissions issue where your application server doesn't have permission to move the images from their current folder `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/`.

Can you change the permissions of the folder to see if that fixes the issue ?

Run the command bellow:

`chmod 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/`

Comment: have you confirmed that the folder now has permissions 777?

Run 
ll -lt one directory up from the applications folder and show the output

Comment: sorry I mean confirm the temp folder has rwxrwxrwx, cd to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles and run ll -lt and show the output

Comment: Couldn't upload the image directly on the comment

Comment: Right in that case, it looks like the apache server doesn't have permissions to access that folder, because it's owned by the user daemon, so you need to change the owner of that folder with chown command to the same user that runs the apache process. So first run this ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)' to get the username of the apache process, and then run sudo chown -R theusernameyoufound:theusernameyoufound /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/

Comment: Obviously replacing in the chown command the two "theusernameyoufound" to whatever you find owns the apache process